# How to cut the output of grep command?

Tags: bash, grep, output, cut

I am running a salt state and using grep to retrieve any checks that have failed. Upon every failure salt by default outputs the following text:

```
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

I want to cut this output from my command so that I can use the actual failure (i.e, the details of which check failed) to be output to a .html file which will be used to display the current state of our environment.

Here is my command:

```
salt --state-output=terse -C 'ServerName' state.sls ldapchecker test=True | grep 'Result: Failed'
```

And here is the output:

```
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code 
Name: /var/log/stunnel.stunnel.log - Function: file.exists - Result: Failed
```

I would like to be left with just the path of the failed check (/var/log/stunnel.stunnel.log)

EDIT: As requested here is the output of:

```
salt --state-output=terse -C 'BCA-AJT-LD-01' state.sls ldapchecker test=True 2>/dev/null

BCA-AJT-LD-01:
  Name: /opt/checkservices.sh - Function: file.managed - Result: Clean
  Name: /var/log/openldap/slapd.log - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /var/log/stunnel.stunnel.log - Function: file.exists - Result: Failed
  Name: /etc/openldap/ldap.conf - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/openldap/certs/cert8.db - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/openldap/certs/key3.db - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/openldap/certs/secmod.db - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/rsyslog.conf - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: salt-master - Function: service.running - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverdetails/serverdetails.sh - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverdetails/servers_list - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverdetails/style.css - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverdetails/test.htm - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverversions/serverversions.sh - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverversions/servers_list - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverversions/style.css - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: /opt/serverversions/test.htm - Function: file.exists - Result: Clean
  Name: rsyslog - Function: service.running - Result: Clean
  Name: salt-minion - Function: service.running - Result: Clean
  Name: sshd - Function: service.running - Result: Clean
  Name: ntpd - Function: service.running - Result: Clean

Summary
-------------
Succeeded: 22
Failed:     1
-------------
Total states run:     23
```

Comment: is it always occupies 2 lines?

Comment: No, it will vary depending on how many errors there are, could realistically be 50+ lines, however that is unlikely.

Comment: and if there consequent 50+ error lines, should it extract and print `/var/log/stunnel.stunnel.log` lines consequently ?

Comment: No, it should print each check that failed. See my edit, it should make it more clear.

Comment: @jto, so you want to print all file names with path right?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, I would like to print just the file path (or name) of each of the above when they failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use single command then awk could help here too.

```
your_command | awk '/^Name:/{print $2}'
```

***EDIT:*** As per your latest edit could you please try following command.

```
your_command | awk '/Name:/ && $2 ~ /\// && $0 ~ /Result: Failed/{print $2}'
```

Comment: It does indeed, thank you for your help! Will this be scalable if there are multiple 'Result :Failed' outputs? @RanvinderSingh13

Comment: @jto, You are welcome, glad that it helped you. Yes it should pick every Result: failed string and whose second column has a path and have string Name: in it, so if 3 of these conditions are meeting in any line then it should fly. Let me know if you have any queries on same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
salt --state-output=terse -C 'ServerName' state.sls ldapchecker test=True | grep 'Result: Failed' | awk -F':|-' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it only output the ERROR: line

Comment: Add the display on prompt part `2>/dev/null` before grep, and then try. I checked with the provided output, and it works.